# Custom order autofield in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have two django models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # some other not important to my question fields

class Field(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
```

`order` field on `Field` class should tell me the order in which fields are going to appear for the `Question`. How can I make it auto increment for the question? For example, I open django admin, add a question, add a field for a question, and when I want to add another field for the same question, I would like to see that order field to be incremented by one, because I already have a field with order number 1. Is there any way to achieve that (auto increment)? I do realize that if I wanted to change the order later, it could be very tedious task. Maybe there are better solutions to this problem I have (manually specifying order of the entries in DB with integer field) than to have a column in a DB?

Comment: Shameless self-plug: https://github.com/iambrandontaylor/django-admin-sortable if you'd like to add drag and drop ordering to those `Field` models.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AutoField` to automatically increment the field, same as the id field.

```
class Field(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    order = models.AutoField(primary_key=False)
```

Or you can do it on your own by overriding the save method:

```
from django.db.models import F


class Field(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.order:
            # Using F object is important
            self.order = F('order') + 1
        return super(Field, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: `save` method is not an option, because it only updates the field post-factum, whereas `AutoField` would fit if it had taken into account question. I mean, for different question counter should start at 1 again.

Comment: AutoFields must set primary_key=True.